# Using Polymorphism Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

My goal is to print out that all the instruments are playing by creating the testInstrument.java file. For some reason I am getting an error for `System.out.println(all[i].play());`

testInstrument.java

```
package my_instruments;

public class testInstrument {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Guitar g = new Guitar();
        Flute f = new Flute();
        Piano p = new Piano();



        Instrument[] all = new Instrument[3];

        all[0] = g;
        all[1] = f;
        all[2] = p;

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.println(all[i].play());
        }


    }

}
```

Instrument.java

```
package my_instruments;

public class Instrument {

public Instrument() {

}

public void play() {
    System.out.println("Playing instrument");
}
}
```

Piano.java

```
package my_instruments;

public class Piano extends Instrument{
public Piano() {
    super();
}

public void play() {
    System.out.println("Playing piano");
}
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Does `play()` method exist in `Instrument` class? Does it return anything? Please post the contents of those classes too.

Comment: Yes the .play() method exists in the Instrument class as well as the Piano, Flute, and Guitar class.

Comment: What is the relationship between an `Instrument` and `Guitar`, `Piano` and `Flute`?  It may seem obvious and apparent to you but without actual source code to go off of, *we're* left in the dark here.

Comment: The error i get is "The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)"

Comment: instead of doing System.out.println(all[i].play()); try just all[i].play()

Comment: In order to print smth, your play() methods should return `String`

Comment: in your case it's the best to proceed as @isaace suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
       all[i].play();
    }
```

The play method is already doing the printing and is not returning anything to print.

Answer (score 1):

your play method() is doing the printing already `System.out.println();` try removing the print statement from your for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    all[i].play();
}
```

or

```
for (Instrument i : all) {
    i.play();
}
```